# Is "all total" grammatically correct?

Tags: phrases, grammaticality, adverbs

> - We have three apples all total.
> - All total, we have 75 bananas.
> - How many cucumbers do we have all total?

I have heard many sentences like this. I always wonder, is this grammatically correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you have misheard the phrase [*all told*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/all%20told). This means *counting everything / everyone*, e.g.

> There were 500 passengers, all told.

Either that or this is an eggcorn of *all told*.

I have not been able to get an NGram for *all total* that is relevant, since the phrase pops up in many circumstances. Also, I've not been able to find instances in google books that use *all total* the way you have.

Comment: This. Just the word I was thinking of. +1.

Comment: +1. Note that the definition you link to says, "This idiom, first recorded in 1850, uses the verb tell in the sense of "count." However, I found a reprint of a publication, [Rare Americana: A Catalogue of Historical and Geographical Books, Pamphlets, & Decorative Maps Relating to America](http://books.google.com/books?id=4zQXAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA25&dq=%22all+told%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-HKiT_CgDe7H6AGEy7TfCA&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=%22all%20told%22&f=false), originally published in 1684 that uses *all told* in the sense of a count.

Comment: @JLG: Cf. "teller" — someone who counts out money in a bank.

Comment: @Robusto. Yep, I understand that. My point was that its use as "counting everything" is **much older** than the Dictionary.com definition states (1850 *vs.* 1684).

Comment: The Eggcorn Database recognizes this as a known eggcorn:
http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/english/559/total/

Comment: Thanks! You're most likely correct, I misheard (several times).

Comment: Or you heard correctly, @Jae, and the people speaking were using an [eggcorn](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eggcorn)

Answer (score 2):

No. It's either "in all" or "in total", you cannot use both "all" and "total".

Comment: Why not?  There's no rule against using both. *All total* does not seem ungrammatical to me (native AmE speaker), though it is less familiar than *all in total* or *all totaled up*.

Comment: "seem" and "grammatical" do not agree. :-)

Comment: I mean that it is grammatical for me, whereas it might not be for you; different speakers will have different grammaticality judgments for something like this that may be regional or have started as an eggcorn. While you're right that *in all* and *in total* are some of the most universally understood alternatives, *cannot use* is perhaps a harsh proscription to describe something people are already doing (*all* and *total* together). :)

Comment: Lots of people are said be increasingly saying "I graduated the university" -- no typo there. We've to wait till the authorities declare that as grammatical (or otherwise).